# Embed private video

Tags: video, youtube, embed, media

We have a requirement for a video to be embedded on a password protected page. The beauty with video hosting/publishing services like YouTube and Vimeo is that it's fast and simple to publish, it's optimized, highly compatible with all the different devices out there, and always up-to-date technology-wise.

There is the option of embedding an unlisted YouTube video, but this wouldn't be completely private. 
What could people recommend as a good, low-cost alternative video hosting/publishing platform that allows for completely private videos to be added to a site.

I'm not so keen on self-hosting as it takes more effort to set up, text and keep up-to-date. Or should this be considered?

Thank you for any options.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://www.vidmeup.com ?

you can fully customise the videos and embed privately...